Need to Pull Ecommerce Data/Form Submit/Conversion Data and Cannot
I apologize as I do not know all the correct terminology.
I am using the following system:
https://snaplyst.aryeo.com/order-forms/018f1146-abf5-7301-a579-045ab5a4ca48
This app/form is not giving me any distinct CSS/ID elements to target in GTM so I am un-aware of how to pull distinct elements from the form.
I'd like to capture Ecommerce data from the form for use with Google Ads. A GTM Tag is embedded into the form and the preview works - it even triggers certain items.

For example, Form Submission will work on a certain area but not when the actual purchase is made.
Another example is Clicks set to "All Elements" that works but when set to a particular ID, it still triggers all clicks - very confusing.

Later, this form will be embedded to the actual site and will use a Listener/Sender script to send from the child GTM to the parent GTM. This already works as clicks were sent over to the parent. Both tags are paused now as I am simply trying to get the correct information/triggers activated.
I even tried a custom element that targets purchases, add-to-carts etc..
Can anyone throw me in the right direction?
Explained in the post above.
